# how to get the next sequence number . in the confirmation message in Junit with selenium

Tags: selenium-rc, junit3

i m using the verification for the text as verifyEquals("Successful Submit:Sequence Number: 911537\n ); but the sequence number keeps on updating on each run.

Can anybody suggest as how to verify the text for each multiple run or how to generate the next sequence number in Junit with selenium rc

Thanks in advance to all

Comment: The questions is what kind of sequence number this is? From database?

Comment: Yes it is retrieve from database and generated at run time/dynamic

Comment: So why would you like to check it? Don't you trust your database ? Or what are you trying to test?

Comment: i am testing an application and i want to verify text which has dynamic element with glob i failed doing, i am using selenium. what should i use to verify the dynamically generated element it has multiple lines too.